# How to use TapTargetView with Jetpack compose

Tags: android, android-jetpack-compose

In my current project https://github.com/KeepSafe/TapTargetView is used to showcase a tutorial for new user. I am planning to convert my project in Jetpack compose. How this library can be used in Composables? Is there any similar library for Jetpack Compose only?

Answer (score 2):

I know I'm late to the party but there's this library inspired by TapTargetView and it's made for Compose: [Intro Showcase View](https://canopas.github.io/Intro-showcase-view/) which is really similar to the original one. Hope others may find this useful.

Answer (score 0):

Better raise an issue in the GitHub repository so the library maintainers can decide to make compose version of the library

There is a way to use existing layouts in compose using [AndroidView](https://foso.github.io/Jetpack-Compose-Playground/viewinterop/androidview/) but I'm not sure about how perfect it will be for this library.

Comment: I also want to know if there are any Compose compatible library which can be utilized.

Comment: At this moment I think none exists since compose is new just got stable (1.0.0) last month but there are on going issues on GitHub like this https://github.com/sjwall/MaterialTapTargetPrompt/issues/197 so you have to wait for that :)

Answer (score 0):

Since all the existing compose implementations have some limitations (glitchy animations, weird placing of the content etc) that make them unsuitable for use in a production app, I ended up making my own implementation: https://github.com/PierfrancescoSoffritti/tap-target-compose